# kml layers google maps limits changed?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

My application does this:

1. generates lots of markers
2. puts them in kml files each with 20k markers
3. exports the files to a server
4. opens each file as a kmllayer and sets the layer to a map object

My problem is:

before the change in the API (a month ago) I could display more than 100k markers on the same map with no problems. IE would be much slower, but still loaded the points correctly most of the time.

now (with no code changed by my side) IE wont even draw a single layer with 10k markers. Chrome can make it to the ~20k but no more than that.
The map simply does not draw a single marker if the number of points is to big.

Do you guys know of any change in the limits? is there any workaround?

the code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="htmlConfig.js" ></script>
    <script>
    var map;    
    function initialize()
    {
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-47.19105,-22.857302);
        var mapOptions =
        {
            zoom: 6,
            center: chicago
                }   

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        for(i = 0; i < _files; i++)
        {
            foo = (_url+'/'+(i)+'.kml');
            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: foo});
            ctaLayer.setMap(map);
        }

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

url is the path to the server and _files is the number of files each named 0.kml, 1.kml and so on

Comment: Did your server name or the paths to the KML files change (_url)?

Comment: I found out that chrome is only not drawing the markers when zoom is far away for some reason. IE is still not working...

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested the software at home and it worked just as it should. So i found out the problem was the web filter IT department installed. Somehow it is messing with the communication with the kml files in the public server or the google servers. Not much to do in this case i guess...

Answer (score 0):

There are limits for KML and are described in this [document](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) primary the limits are on the size of the kml and not in the number of elements

Comment: Yes but the kml size is proportional to the number of elements

Answer (score 0):

[Reference to the URL length limit in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport#size-and-complexity-restrictions-for-kml-rendering-in-google-maps):

> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will display. The limit is based on the total length of all URLs passed to the KMLLayer class, and consequently will vary by application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit.

The restriction may have changed based on a change to the API.

Try reducing the length of the URLs to your KML files by using a "URL Shortener" (like [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/)).

Comment: Do you use custom icons for the markers? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue